# ARM: how to obtain current context

Tags: c++, embedded, arm

The question is related to the ARMv6.

I'm implementing a backtrace routine for our embedded app. I'm using gcc 4.7.3 with uClibc-0.9.33.2. gcc complains about function getcontext:

```
ucontext_t *context;
getcontext(context); // getcontext was not declared in this scope
```

I've looked into ucontext.h and have not found any function to get the current context. Here is the question: how can I get current context on ARM? I need somehow fill ucontext_t structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need a newer uClibc - http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2013-January/047400.html suggests the getcontext patches were posted in Jan 2013 whereas the version you are running is from May 2012. Two options - try latest git or backport the patches.